# Trigger created with compilation errors. ORA-:missing SELECT keyword

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger that fires after an insert/update and checks for null values in couple of columns. In case any one of them is NULL, it queries other tables and updates the current table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sample_trigger
 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON test_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.ID IS NULL OR :NEW.CODE IS NULL
THEN    
  UPDATE (:NEW.ID,:NEW.CODE) = (SELECT T1.ID,
                                          T2.CODE
                                          FROM TABLE_1 T1
                                          JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
                                          WHERE ID=:NEW.TEST_ID);                     

END IF;

END;
/

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
ERROR: PL/SQL: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't `UPDATE` the `:new` pseudo-record.  Just assign values to it

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.code
  INTO :new.id, :new.code
  FROM table1 t1
       join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 WHERE id = :new.test_id
```

A couple additional notes

- Your `WHERE` clause will generate an ambiguous reference error.  Since both `t1` and `t2` have an `ID` column, you'd need to specify which table's column you are comparing against.
- If `test_table` is the same as either `table_1` or `table_2`, that's going to produce a mutating table exception.
- Your trigger should be a `BEFORE INSERT` since it's modifying data not an `AFTER INSERT` trigger.

Comment: Thank you @Justin. test_table is a different one not either table_1 or table_2

Answer (score 0):

Triggers have to follow syntax as any other program unit; `UPDATE` you wrote is invalid (obviously), but - you don't need it. Here's what you might have done:

- declare two variables which will hold ID and CODE values
- set TEST_TABLES's columns values to those variables

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sample_trigger
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON test_table
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_id   test_table.id%type;
  l_code test_table.code%type;
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.ID IS NULL OR :NEW.CODE IS NULL
  THEN
    SELECT t1.id, t2.code
      INTO l_id , l_code
      FROM table_1 t1 JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
      WHERE id = :new.test_id;

    :new.id   := l_id;
    :new.code := l_code;

  END IF;
END;
/
```